# numba exception when run from inside IDE (VS2015)

Tags: python, visual-studio, anaconda, numba, ptvs

I have visual studio 2015 with PTVS, tested with both Anaconda Python 3.4 and 3.5 (64 bit).

I get an exception immediately when the the script imports numba, this is a minimal example:

```
import numba
```

The exception is:

```
dictionary changed size during iteration
```

The exception originates from

```
envs\python3.5\Lib\site-packages\numba\config.py line 169
```

It appears that only inside VS the following code gives an error, note that it iterates over `locals()` and is updating `globals()`

```
for name, value in locals().items():
        if name.isupper():
            globals()[name] = value
```

Running the script from the Interactive window, in NVidia's Visual Profiler, jupyter notebook/command line interpreter works just fine so I suspect it must be something related to visual studio.

When I compare the contents of `sys.modules` between environments I find that visual studio imports some additional modules when debugging

```
'visualstudio_py_debugger',
'visualstudio_py_repl', 
'visualstudio_py_util'
```

Otherwise no differences between the environments. Also, scripts without `numba` don't throw any exceptions when importing them to VS. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outside of a function locals() and globals() refer to the same datastructure. Python does not allow changing a datastructure that is being iterated over. 
This has been fixed in the library in this commit
https://github.com/numba/numba/commit/e50ab6ee4d95192d364cccced36cf0889860d023